# Proving an operator is contractive

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I am having trouble with the following problem:

> a) Let $H_n (x), n \in \mathbb{N}$ be Hermite polynomials associated to
> the measure $$ d \mu = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}d
>  \lambda $$ Prove that the following
> operator is contractive in $\mathbb{L}^2(\mathbb{R}, \mu)$ for $\zeta \le 1$:
> $$T_{n}f(x) = H_k(x) + \zeta H_n(x)\int H_n(y)f(y) \mu(dy) $$

The solution is as follows:
$$\|T_nf(x)-T_n g(x)\|^2 = \int|\zeta|^2 H_n(x)^2 |\int H_n(y)(f(y)-g(y)) \mu(dy)|^2 \mu(dx)$$ and hence $$ \|T_nf - T_ng\| = |\zeta| \|f-g\|$$
My question:

- How do they get from the first line to the second line? I believe it is something to do with some property of the measure but I don't see how its done. I've been staring at it for a while. If anyone could spell out the argument I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Hermite polynomials are orthonormal according to that measure. So the first line is the square of the second one.

Comment: @Icv okay, so I see that means the first integral is simply $| \zeta |^2$. but why is the second integral equal to $\|f-g\|^2$?

Comment: $\zeta$ is a constant. The Hermite polynomials form an orthonormal basis. The conclusion follows from the Parseval identity.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you, I understand it now :)

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Actually sorry I'm looking over it again... how does Parseval apply here? Because Parseval says  $ \sum_{n} \langle f, H_n \rangle = \|f\|^2$ but here we are not summing over $n$? In the expression in my post we have just $\langle f, H_n \rangle$ and not the sum of all such terms.

Comment: @duelspace You are right. Hence we have $$ \|T_nf - T_ng\| \le |\zeta| \|f-g\|$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Are you sure we can't have equality somehow? Because the solution has an equality here. Furthermore in the second part of the question we are asked to show it is not strictly contractive for $\zeta = 1$. Again I think we need the equality to show this because otherwise the bound is too crude.

Comment: @duelspace The equality holds if $f$ and $g$ are multiples of $H_n.$ But if $f=g=H_{n+1}$ then $T_nf=T_ng=H_k.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I agree with what you have said here, but I meant do we have the equality: $$ \|T_nf - T_ng\| = |\zeta| \|f-g\|$$ for any $f,g \in L^2$? This is troubling me because the solution indicates we have equality but I can't see how, neither could I construct $f,g$ which give a strict inequality.

Comment: @duelspace No, for $f=H_{n+1}$ and $g=H_{n+2}$ we have $T_nf=T_ng=H_k.$ So $\|T_nf-T_ng\|=0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Ah right of course! Thank you so much.